# K8s Create Deployment with EnvFrom

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to fire up an influxdb instance on my cluster.

I am following a few different guides and am trying to get it to expose a secret as environment variables using the envFrom operator. Unfortunately I am always getting the `Environment: <none>` after doing my deployment. Doing an echo on the environment variables I expect yields a blank value as well.

I am running this command to deploy (the script below is in influxdb.yaml): kubectl create deployment `influxdb --image=influxdb`

Here is my deployment script:

```
 apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
 kind: Deployment
 metadata:
   creationTimestamp: null
   generation: 1
   labels:
     app: influxdb
     project: pihole
   name: influxdb
 spec:
   progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
   replicas: 1
   revisionHistoryLimit: 10
   selector:
     matchLabels:
       app: influxdb
   strategy:
     rollingUpdate:
       maxSurge: 25%
       maxUnavailable: 25%
     type: RollingUpdate
   template:
     metadata:
       creationTimestamp: null
       labels:
         app: influxdb
     spec:
       containers:
       - name: influxdb
         envFrom:
         - secretRef:
             name: influxdb-creds
         image: docker.io/influxdb:1.7.6
         imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
         resources: {}
         terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
         terminationMessagePolicy: File
         volumeMounts:
         - mountPath: /var/lib/influxdb
           name: var-lib-influxdb
       dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
       restartPolicy: Always
       schedulerName: default-scheduler
       securityContext: {}
       terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
       volumes:
       - name: var-lib-influxdb
         persistentVolumeClaim:
           claimName: influxdb
 status: {}
```

The output of kubectl describe secret influxdb-creds is this:

```
Name:         influxdb-creds
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Type:  Opaque

Data
====
INFLUXDB_USERNAME:  4 bytes
INFLUXDB_DATABASE:  6 bytes
INFLUXDB_HOST:      8 bytes
INFLUXDB_PASSWORD:  11 bytes
```

Comment: Have you created secret file influxdb-creds ?

Comment: Yes I have. That's what the second set of output shows.

Answer (score 0):

to test your deployment, please first create secrets and later create deployment:

```
1. Secrets:
kubectl create secret generic influxdb-creds --from-literal=INFLUXDB_USERNAME='test_user' --from-literal=INFLUXDB_DATABASE='test_password'

2. Deployment:
kubectl apply -f <path_to_your_yaml_file>
```

In order to verify, please run

```
kubectl describe secret influxdb-creds

kubectl exec <your_new_deployed_pod>  -- env
kubectl describe pod <your_new_deployed_pod>
```

Take a look at:

```
Environment Variables from:
      influxdb-creds  Secret  Optional: false
```

Hope this help.

Please share with your findings.

Comment: That's exactly what I have done and am getting that Environment: <none> instead of  the output you are stating. The second set of output above is the output from describing that secret.

Comment: please provide command you are performing to get this value. It seems you are looking for 'Containers: Environment:'

Comment: Running this command for that output: kubectl describe deployment influxdb
This is what I see in that command's output that should show the environment variable piece:
Containers:
   influxdb:
    Image:        influxdb
    Port:         <none>
    Host Port:    <none>
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:       <none>
    Volumes:        <none>

Comment: Hi Khirok, in this example you can't find those values, because they weren't defined in your deployment.
Please specify in details what you are asking about and where is the problem.
Please attach commands you are performing and the results to show the community what kind of problems you have.

Here you can find more information about [Deployments](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/), [defining env varaibles](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is that I was creating the deployment incorrectly. I was using the command `kubectl create deployment influxdb --image=influxdb` which was creating a blank deployment and instead I should have been creating it with `kubectl create -f influxdb.yaml` where influxdb.yaml was my file that contained the deployment definition in the original question.

I was making the false assumption that the create deployment command read the yaml file by the same name, but it does not.